# Node Js Restapi - Calling Post Method in Flutter Doesn't Work

Tags: rest, api, dart, flutter

I have local api and jwt by node js i want to send my username and password from flutter and send it to node js to give me this token and later i will save it in local storage but when i tell flutter post to the api doesn't post

my code :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use http method here like below Future example

```
Future postContact(access_token,name,email,phone,message) async {
  String apiUrl = '$_apiUrl/user/contact-us';
  http.Response response = await http.post(apiUrl,headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accesstoken": "Bearer $access_token"
  }, body:  {'name':'$name','email':'$email','phone':'$phone','message':'$message'});
  print("Result: ${response.body}");
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```